# Samba as PDC on ubuntu 12.04.5

Tags: 12.04, lts

Windows 7, 8 , and 10 machines are unable to join to samba(PDC).when i enter domain  username and password i get the message:

The following error occured attempting to join domain "xxxxx". The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

Any ideas? I run a network of about 150 computers,and want each user to login to domain for control reasons

Ken.

Comment: please refer [here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Required_settings_for_NT4-style_domains)

Answer (score 0):

I to have recently setup this up in my office to and DNS is an absolute key when it comes to Domain Controllers, I have you changed the DNS server settings on the client PC's? On windows if you go to:

Network and sharing Center -> Change adapter settings -> Right click & properties -> IPv4 settings -> and change the DNS server address in the bottom field to the IP address of the PDC.

If you configure client PC's IP settings through your router than you need to set the DNS server config to the IP of your server.

Also make sure your PDC resolves to its own IP address when you use lookup.

One other issue I encountered when I set this up was my clients had not internet connection and it required me to change my DNS forwarder in /etc/samba/smb.conf to google's DNS which is 8.8.8.8.

I am no expert so somebody may correct me but i faced similar issues and this is how i resolved them!

Comment: Let me try the DNS way and see if this resolves my problem.Although usually there should be no tunning of windows machines to join them to samba PDC. my samba configurations  works fine,just cant figure out why windows machines cant join?

Comment: I had the exact same issue and it was resolved when I pointed the DNS and the server!

Comment: If this answer was correct could you please mark it as so!

Comment: Dan,have tried  follow your route but am still experiencing same thing. i want to reboot my server and see if this will clear the error. Am running squid on same server,have to wait when few users are using it.

Comment: How did you config your domain controller? Using the domain provisioning tool or manually config the file?

Comment: I used vi editor to manually configure smb.conf file

Comment: am doing fresh re-install of samba and try again the configuration of the smb.conf file. Will let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: https://jimshaver.net/2014/07/13/setting-up-an-active-directory-domain-controller-using-samba-4-on-ubuntu-14-04/ is a great tutorial for using provisioning the samba domain, I haven't tried on ubuntu 12.02 but it may be worth ago!